# Pallets disappear when storing into the pallet rack

Tags: anylogic

Suddenly my different pallets disappear when I store them into my pallet rack. Before the forklifts stores them, they are visible. After they store them into the pallet rack they get invisible. I tried the function to make them visible after storing but it doesn't work. When I change the type in my delay block from a specified time to unit stop delay is called they are visible but the types look completely different and very big.

delayblock:
[image: delayblock]

rackstore:
[image: rackstore]

secondsafterrackstore:
[image: secondsafterrackstore]

process:
[image: process]

delaychanged:
[image: delaychanged]

Comment: Well, what change did you make so they "suddenly" disappeared? This will make it a lot easier to help you ensure it stays visible ;-)

Comment: I create a new network and new pallet racks

Comment: aha, thx. Now add those details to your question. How was it before, what exactly did you change (screenshots, annotations...) and what have you tried yourself. Make it brief, easy to follow and well-structured and off we go together :D

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you very much Benjamin for your help!

Comment: Cool, well done. Why not share here so others can benefit in future searches? ;)